# Can express identify request in global scope?

Tags: node.js, express

```
//This is assumption it works
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const execute = () => {
  const request = express.Request;
  console.log(request.app.locals.requestId);
};

router.get('/test1', (req, res) => {
  req.app.locals.requestId = 1;
  setTimeout(() => {
    execute();  // epxect log 1
  }, 2000);

});


router.get('/test2', (req, res) => {
  req.app.locals.requestId = 2;
  setTimeout(() => {
    execute();  // epxect log 2
  }, 1000);
});

router.get('/test3', (req, res) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    execute();  // epxect log undefined
  }, 3000);
});
```

I expect I can get requestId without pass req to all functions, where function I need to get, I can get from express.Request. And all request is not replace each other.
If request test2 run later but done before, it not replace requestId of request test1

Comment: An individual Express request is NOT globally available and because of asynchronous operations, multiple express requests can be in flight at the same time.  If you want the `req` object available to some other code that is involved in the request processing, then you should either pass the `req` object to that function  or somehow use local functions and scoping to make `req` available.  Do not assign it to a global as that will just create conflicts when more than one request is being worked on.

Comment: There has been some work in nodejs with "thread local variables" that might provide a place to put something like the current request object, but as far as I know these have all been experiments and are not production ready.